# How do I extract a substring starting from end of string until the second 0 is encountered, oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

I have a table `client_requests` with the column `number_request`.
In the column `number_request` I have the following records:

```
20130000000008,
20130000000010,
20130000000503
```

I want to extract only the end of string without 0,

example:

```
for 20130000000008 I want to get 8
for 20130000000010 I want to get 10
for 20130000000503 I want to get 503
```

I think I need to use `regexp_substr` but do not know how.

Comment: It is required to define the starting position because the result of 20130000000503 could be 3, 503 or 130000000503.

Comment: Thank You, i found a solution. I get max(number_request) then i use a to_number for substring that start from first position (in the string) of a number <> 0 to end. In my case max(number_request) was 20150000001118, then my solutin is to_number(substr(number_requests,11,14). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

```
select replace('201500000010',regexp_substr('201500000010','.{4}0*'),'') from dual;
```

Essentially, I'm using the regexp_subst function to extract the unwanted digits, then using the replace function to replace the unwanted digits with '', which is nothing.